# Como ordenar uma data que está no formato varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
    SELECT a.nome, a.cidade, a.telefone, a.dt_criado
      FROM cadastro AS a
  GROUP BY a.nome, a.cidade, a.telefone, a.dt_criado 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 
     ORDER BY a.dt_criado 
      DESC
```

**a.dt_criado** é um varchar, mas não ordena corretamente.

Resultado do select:

> 02/05/2018 - 15:38:21 02/05/2018 - 15:39:48 02/05/2018 - 15:40:05
>   02/05/2018 - 15:44:19 02/05/2018 - 17:41:42 03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
>   03/05/2018 - 08:53:06 03/05/2018 - 08:53:06 03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
>   03/05/2018 - 08:53:06 03/05/2018 - 08:53:06 03/05/2018 - 14:11:29
>   03/05/2018 - 14:12:04 03/05/2018 - 14:13:06 03/05/2018 - 14:48:59
>   20/04/2018 - 09:35:59 20/04/2018 - 12:38:13 20/04/2018 - 16:49:15
>   20/04/2018 - 16:49:31 20/04/2018 - 16:55:23 20/04/2018 - 16:55:23
>   20/04/2018 - 16:55:23 –

Comment: Voce poderia postar uma pequena amostragem do conteúdo? E postariormente como ele fica após o order by?

Comment: dt_criado
02/05/2018 - 15:38:21
02/05/2018 - 15:39:48
02/05/2018 - 15:40:05
02/05/2018 - 15:44:19
02/05/2018 - 17:41:42
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 08:53:06
03/05/2018 - 14:11:29
03/05/2018 - 14:12:04
03/05/2018 - 14:13:06
03/05/2018 - 14:48:59
20/04/2018 - 09:35:59
20/04/2018 - 12:38:13
20/04/2018 - 16:49:15
20/04/2018 - 16:49:31
20/04/2018 - 16:55:23
20/04/2018 - 16:55:23
20/04/2018 - 16:55:23

Comment: troca para `order by Convert(datetime,a.dt_criado,103) desc`

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Fiz uma mudança, é datetime em vez de date

Comment: agora deu: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Tem alguma data sua incompleta. Vou postar um Fiddle pra vc ver!

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca821/1

Comment: Tive um problema parecido em Oracle por uma tabela legada com um campo "data" que é uma string , fiz o seguinte uma function converte para string para date , mas em um bloco protegido tratando erro de conversão e retornando nulo neste caso, não é a melhor das soluções mas foi o possível.

Comment: aparentemente pelo sqlfiddle tudo normal....

Comment: talvez se ordernar só pelo dia/mes/ano já ajudava mesmo que não pegue a hora...tem como fazer ums substring será?

Answer (score 5):

A conversão directa usando `CONVERT(DATETIME, _a_sua_data_, 103)` não está a funcionar devido ao '-' que separa a data e a hora. Penso que isto não seja um formato standard do SQL Server.

Uma solução possível passa por remover o '-' e após isto efectuar a conversão.

```
CREATE TABLE Testes
(
  coluna_data VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Testes(coluna_data) VALUES
('02/03/2018 - 22:45:01'), 
('02/05/2018 - 12:56:03'), 
('02/05/2018 - 14:22:03'), 
('02/05/2018 - 19:39:22'), 
('02/05/2018 - 12:46:45'), 
('03/06/2018 - 06:34:52'), 
('03/04/2018 - 02:35:09')

SELECT coluna_data 
  FROM Testes
 ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(coluna_data, '-', ''), 103)
```

O resultado é o esperado

```
coluna_data

02/03/2018 - 22:45:01 
03/04/2018 - 02:35:09 
02/05/2018 - 12:46:45 
02/05/2018 - 12:56:03 
02/05/2018 - 14:22:03 
02/05/2018 - 19:39:22 
03/06/2018 - 06:34:52
```

Veja também o [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e348e/1)

Comment: Na mosca! Muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente